# ComboBox.ObjectCollection doesn't update if the new value's string representation is case-insensitively equal to the current value

Tags: c#, .net

If I try to change a value in a `ComboBox`'s `Items`, it will only actually update if the new value is different from the current value after a *case-insensitive* compare.

Let's make a `ComboBox` with one item:

```cs
ComboBox cboBox = new ComboBox();
cboBox.Items.Add("Apple");
```

The following code will make the `ComboBox` still show "Apple", even though the string should look different:

```
cboBox.Items[0] = "APPLE";
```

And the naive workaround that I've been using, which will make it display correctly:

```
cboBox.Items[0] = "";
cboBox.Items[0] = "APPLE";
```

I wanted to figure out how this was happening, so I dug around with a reflector and found this. This is the `ComboBox.ObjectCollection.SetItemInternal` method that gets called when you try to modify a value:

```cs
internal void SetItemInternal(int index, object value)
{
    ...

    this.InnerList[index] = value;
    if (this.owner.IsHandleCreated)
    {
        bool flag = index == this.owner.SelectedIndex;
        if (string.Compare(this.owner.GetItemText(value), this.owner.NativeGetItemText(index), true, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture) != 0)
        {
            this.owner.NativeRemoveAt(index);
            this.owner.NativeInsert(index, value);
            if (flag)
            {
                this.owner.SelectedIndex = index;
                this.owner.UpdateText();
            }
            if (this.owner.AutoCompleteSource == AutoCompleteSource.ListItems)
            {
                this.owner.SetAutoComplete(false, false);
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (flag)
            {
                this.owner.OnSelectedItemChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
                this.owner.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That `true` in `string.Compare` is telling it to ignore the case of the string. Why was this method chosen for deciding whether or not to update the value? And why didn't they expose the case sensitivity?

Is there an alternative way to update an item in an `ObjectCollection` so that I don't have to guess whether or not it actually gets updated?

**EDIT**: I should note that the `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDownList`: this is a read-only `ComboBox` that occasionally needs to be updated due to actions elsewhere in the program.

Comment: but this.InnerList[index] = value; what is this innerlist?. Have you tried, after changing the value, to dropdown the combo? Is the item changed there?

Comment: `InnerList` is a private `ArrayList`. After changing the value and dropping-down the list, the item is not visibly changed; it still says "Apple".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After submitting a report to the MSDN, it was marked as "by-design" and nothing more, so that's that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add a SelectedIndexChanged event, and inside it put:

```
int index = cboBox.SelectedIndex;
if (index - 1 >= 0) {
cboBox.SelectedIndex = index - 1;
cboBox.SelectedIndex = index;
}
else if (index + 1 < cboBox.InnerList.Count) {
cboBox.SelectedIndex = index + 1;
cboBox.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

This is probably as "naive" as your work around, but maybe worth a try?

Comment: Unfortunately it fails to update regardless of whether or not it's the currently selected item. So if I were to add a "Banana" to that list, select it, and then try changing "Apple" to "APPLE", the problem still happens. There's nothing I can do to the ComboBox with my mouse that'll force it to update.